# NFS mount shows with df -h but directory is not there

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, nfs

I am trying to sort out autofs issues by manually mounting from an Odroid HC1 server running OpenMediaVault 5 to an Odroid XU4, both running Ubuntu.

When I do:

```
sudo mount -t nfs HC1:/export/work /nfs_mounts
```

then run `df -h` it shows:

```
HC1:/export/work 458G 73M 458G 1% /nfs_mounts
```

But when I try `cd /nfs_mounts/work` (as a user that exists on both the XU4 and the HC1 or as root) it tells me that there is no such file or directory, and `ls` shows that the directory is empty.

I have tried it with `-t nfs4` as well, and without any `-t` option, but the result is the same.

The shared folder `/export/work` shows up on the server with `showmount`.

I have searched and searched but I'm stumped.

Comment: `df -h` shows you `/nfs_mounts` exists. `cd /nfs_mounts/work` shows tells you `/nfs_mounts/work` does not exist. These are *different* directories, there is no contradiction. Have you tried `cd /nfs_mounts` and `ls` there? The title would make more sense if you got `cd: /nfs_mounts: no such file or directory`; but this is not the case, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the local `/nfs_mounts` now equals to the remote `/export/work`? Since you did `mount -t nfs HC1:/export/work /nfs_mounts` instead of `mount -t nfs HC1:/export/work /nfs_mounts/work` (with `mkdir /nfs_mounts/work` done beforehand).

Comment: That makes sense. I was confused, because the directions I was following for autofs (with "/nfs_mounts /etc/auto.nfs" in auto.master and "/work HC1:/export/work" in auto.nfs) stated that: "Note that the folders /nfs_mounts/netopt, /nfs_mounts/homes, and /nfs_mounts/work do not exist at this stage, will, however, become available upon starting the automounter." That made me think that the mount command above would populate the dir /nfs_mounts with the /work dir.